# Applications of the Dold-Thom theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Say $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex.
The Dold-Thom theorem states that $\pi_i SP(X) \cong \tilde{H}_i(X;\mathbb{Z})$, where 
$SP(X)$ denotes the infinite symmetric product of $X$.

I am just curious about some *useful* applications of this theorem or instances where this theorem simplifies calculations significantly.

Answer (score 4):

For one you can get the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in homology almost immediately from a homotopy pushout, but depending on what angle you look at it from, that may not be that useful (as in, to prove the theorem, you need to define the functor $H_*$ anyway, and then you probably already know it satisfies M-V).

You can deduce a group structure on the Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces, see this [previous M.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45556/group-structure-on-eilenberg-maclane-spaces). (In fact it is probably possible to prove the existence of the Eilenberg-Mac Lane space using Dold-Thom)

At a philosophical level I can do no more than point you to Thomas Barnet-Lamb's excellent piece on [Dold-Thom](http://people.brandeis.edu/~tbl/dold-thom.pdf), and some of the reasons why it is important.

Comment: Thank your for the reference to Thomas Barnet-Lamb's paper. I will take a look at it in more depth tonight. I know about the direct applications/corollaries (For example those in Hatcher) of the theorem but I am more curious about its usefulness in computations or other places where it arises.