# Why are higher homology groups not the abelianizations of higher homotopy groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Really the question is exactly the title:

> Why (conceptually and geometrically if possible) are higher homology groups not the abelianizations of higher homotopy groups?

Comment: Because the higher homotopy groups are abelian, that would result in nothing useful.

Comment: It would probably be useful if you told us what reason you have to expect this to be true.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I saw that $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1$. I want to understand what exactly is it that makes this no longer true in higher dimensions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez could you please explain why abelian higher homotopy groups would results in nothing useful?

Comment: As the higher homotopy groups are abelian abelianizing them does nothing to them.

Comment: I suggest thorougly understanding an example, for instance $\pi_3(S^2) \approx \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_3(S^2) \approx 0$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez oh, I thought you meant something else. Of course my question was about why $H_n$ are not their abelianizations.

Comment: There's no good reason for the higher homotopy groups and homology groups to agree. Dimension 1 is very special: it's easy to realize a $1$-cycle as a loop (not so for $n$-cycles and maps from the $n$-sphere); and that null-homologous loops come from elements of $[\pi_1,\pi_1]$ is essentially because the topology of 1-dimensional complexes is very simple. I suggest you look at the proof and see why it super duper doesn't generalize.

Comment: @MikeMiller this is what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Tangentially: in a sense, higher homology groups are higher homotopy groups of the abelianization of the space (i.e. [by Dold-Thom/Kan $H_i(X)\cong\pi_i(\mathbb Z[X])$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/45592/)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a paper Daniel M. Kan, *A combinatorial definition of homotopy groups*, Ann. of Math. (2) 67 (1958), 282–312s, that actually shows rather nicely that *in certain contexts*, the higher homology groups ARE abelianizations of higher homotopy groups. The Hurewicz theorem also gives a context in which this is true.

[The paper.](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970006?sid=21104942545481&uid=2&uid=3739888&uid=4&uid=3739256) "Chapter III" describes "in precisely what sense the homology groups are abelianized homotopy groups," according to the third paragraph of the introduction.

Answer (score 5):

By triangulating the sphere, there's a map $\pi_n(X,x_0) \to H_n(X;\Bbb Z)$ for all $n$ (after noting that homotopic maps are sent to homologous cycles). This is known as the Hurewicz homomorphism. The theorem you want is

> The Hurewicz homomorphism for $n=1$ is surjective with kernel $[\pi_1(X,x_0),\pi_1(X,x_0)]$.

Surjectivity is easy here, because every $1$-cycle can easily be represented by a (homologous) map $S^1 \to X$. Our first problem with generalizing is that there's no obvious way to represent an $n$-cycle as a map from the $n$-sphere; indeed, $H_2(T^2) \cong \Bbb Z$, but $\pi_2(T^2) = 0$. (To see the latter, note that because $S^2$ is simply connected, you can lift a map $S^2 \to T^2$ to its universal cover $\Bbb R^2$, which is contractible. Now project this null-homotopy back down.)

Even if you have surjectivity, there's the problem of calculating the kernel. I would say that this is possible precisely because 1-cycles are so simple and there's not much data to carry around; you may disagree. Either way, I suggest reading the actual proof; you can find it e.g. in Hatcher's algebraic topology book, theorem 2A.1.

All this is what makes the following theorem (the Hurewicz theorem) sort of miraculous.

> Let $X$ be simply connected and let $m$ be the least integer such that $\pi_m(X)$ is nonzero. Then $H_k(X)=0$ for $k<m$ and the Hurewicz homomorphism for $n=m$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a closed n-dimensional submanifold $M\subset X$, then you can triangulate it and get a cycle that represents an element in $H_n(X;{\mathbb Z})$. (It might be trivial, and in higher dimensions not all homology classes of a manifold are obtains this way, but never mind, it's just an example.)

If $M$ was an embedded n-sphere, then it also represents an element in $\pi_nX$. (I.e., the homology class is in the image of the Hurewicz homomorphism.) But in general, if $M$ is not a sphere, then the homology class will not be represented by an element of the homotopy group.

For example, consider a Torus or a surface of higher genus. By triangulating it you get an element in the second homology. But this element will not be representable by a sphere, so $\pi_2\to H_2$ is not surjective in this case.