Extension of group action with higher homotopy groups
Given a topological space $X$ with a group action $ \varphi : G \times X \to X$, we can construct a group extension with $\pi_1(X)$ as follows:
Take the universal cover $\pi : \tilde X \to X$ and consider the set of lifts:
$$L_1= \{ (\tilde f,g) \in \text{Homeo}(\tilde X)\times G :  \pi\circ \tilde f = \varphi(g) \circ \pi\} $$
By identifying the associated deck transformation with an element of $\pi_1(X)$ then we get a group extension:
$$ 0 \to \pi_1(X) \to L_1 \to G \to 0 $$
Question: Does there exist a similar extension for higher homotopy groups?
My idea would be to use the $n^{th}$ stage $X_n$ of the Whitehead tower, since this is the $n$-connected version of the universal cover. This stage sits in a fibration with fiber $K(\pi_n(X), n-1)$. I am wondering if we perform the same construction as $L_1$, except we lift to $X_n$ instead of $\tilde X$, if we get a group extension:
$$ 0 \to K(\pi_n(X),n-1) \to L_n \to G \to 0 $$
Idea: Maybe one way to do this would be to consider the loop space $\Omega^{n-1}X$, since we know that $\pi_1(\Omega^{n-1}X)=\pi_n(X)$. Then maybe a similar argument to the universal cover extension could be used? However this would seem to require inducing the $G$-action on $X$ to a $G$-action on $\Omega^{n-1}X$. I am confused about how to do this if the $G$-action is free, and so does not preserve the basepoint of the loop space.
Edit: fixed $L_1$ definition

Could  you  please  give  a clear  definition of  $L_1$. In this  current  form I think some  thing is  missing.

Neat question! It looks like the compositions are backwards in $L_1$. Also, I suppose you have to argue that $L_1 \to G$ is surjective -- a priori, maybe there is some $g$ such that there is no automorphism of the universal cover which descends to the action of $g$ on $X$.

@AliTaghavi I think what OP means is: an element of $L_1$ is an element of $G$ (viewed as a homeomorphism of $X$) together with a homeomorphism of $\widetilde{X}$ lifting it. (Symbolically, this is what you get from what OP wrote if you swap both the orders of composition, and interpret $\phi(g)$ to mean the homeomorphism $x \mapsto \phi(g, x)$ from $X$ to itself).

@hunter Thanks! I think if $G$ is connected then surjectivity could be argued using the homotopy lifting property. That is, we could consider a homotopy from any $g$-action to the identity, and lift this to the universal cover

should there be a $\pi_1$ or something in the first term of the proposed sequence? (like the fundamental group of the eilenberg maclane space?)

oh or do you just mean $\pi_n(X)$?

@hunter I am not entirely sure. I guess the question boils down to the existence of some higher-homotopy analogue of a deck transformation. I am hoping that maybe this can be formalized using the natural group structure on the Eilenberg-Maclane space as described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45556/group-structure-on-eilenberg-maclane-spaces

@FirstAid got it, didn't know about that group structure! If something like this is going to be true, then $G$ has to act on the abelianization of that group, is there a natural reason to think that?

(I guess that group is abelian.)

@hunter I think a sufficient condition for the extension is that there should be an inclusion of $K(\pi_n(X), n-1) \subset \text{Homeo}(X_n)$ by the abelian group action on the fibers . Maybe this is enough to conclude that such an extension exists?
